# Spring @ResponseBody get data to populate dataTable Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, datatable

First of all, exuse my English.

I am new to JQuery and DataTable.

I have a problem with JQuery dataTable for results and populate the list.
I have an object in the controller to return toResponseBody retrieving data from the database. So far so ok.
When I send the data to the jsp just show me the results in json format but does not assign the dataTable. What am I doing wrong or what I lack for the results to be correctly rendered.

Controller

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadAlbaranes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody XxxView loadAlbaranes(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @Valid
        @ModelAttribute ("view") XxxView view,
        BindingResult result, Locale locale) {

    if(getLogService().getLog(this.getClass()).isDebugEnabled())
        getLogService().getLog(this.getClass()).info("loadAlbaranes <-- ");


    ValidationResultDTO validations = null;
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        validations = new ValidationResultDTO();
        validations.setMessage("Errores de validacion");
        validations.setErrors(validationMessages(result, locale));

        view.setValidationResultDTO(validations);

    }else{
        ...

        List<Qry011DTO> albaranesList;
        DataTableDTO<Qry011DTO> albaranesResult = new DataTableDTO<Qry011DTO>();
        try {
            albaranesList = albaranRPGService.getAlbaranes(params);

            albaranesResult.setAaData(albaranesList);
            int count = albaranesList.size();
            albaranesResult.setiTotalDisplayRecords(count);
            albaranesResult.setiTotalRecords(count);

            view.setAlbaranList(albaranesResult);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogService().getLog(this.getClass()).error("Error recuperando datos de albaranes [ ERROR: "+e.getMessage() +" ]");

            ValidationErrorDTO valErr = new ValidationErrorDTO();

            validations = new ValidationResultDTO();
            validations.setMessage("Error");
            valErr.setMessage("Error recuperando datos de albaranes \n[ ERROR: "+e.getMessage().toString() +" ]");
            List<ValidationErrorDTO> errList = new ArrayList<ValidationErrorDTO>();
            errList.add(valErr);

            validations.setErrors(errList);

            view.setValidationResultDTO(validations);
        }

    }

    if(getLogService().getLog(this.getClass()).isDebugEnabled())
        getLogService().getLog(this.getClass()).info("loadAlbaranes --> ");

    return view;
}
```

In XxxView I have `private DataTableDTO<?> albaranList;` with their respective getter and setter the DataTableDTO has structure

```
public class DataTableDTO<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1991375252597373703L;

    private List<T> aaData;

    private Integer iTotalRecords;
    private Integer iTotalDisplayRecords;

    public List<T> getAaData() {
        return aaData;
    }
    public void setAaData(List<T> aaData) {
        this.aaData = aaData;
    }
    public Integer getiTotalRecords() {
        return iTotalRecords;
    }
    public void setiTotalRecords(Integer iTotalRecords) {
        this.iTotalRecords = iTotalRecords;
    }
    public Integer getiTotalDisplayRecords() {
        return iTotalDisplayRecords;
    }
    public void setiTotalDisplayRecords(Integer iTotalDisplayRecords) {
        this.iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords;
    }

}
```

This is the JS function into button search

```
function loadAlbaranes(){
         if (validateForm()) {
                var valueSerie = $("#frmPeparaPedidoFltr #serieAlbaran").val();
                var valueAlbaran = $("#frmPeparaPedidoFltr #numAlbaran").val();

                oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
                    "sAjaxSource" : '/loadAlbaranes',
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide" : true,
                    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                            aoData.push( {"name":'serieAlbaran' , "value" : valueSerie} );
                            aoData.push( {"name":'numAlbaran' , "value" : valueAlbaran} );
                    },


                    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aaData, fnCallback ) {

                        console.log(aaData);

                    },

                    "bDestroy": true, //Para reinstanciar la tabla.
                    "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
                    "aoColumns": [
                                   { "mData": "ptoStock" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: true, sWidth: "10%"},
                                   { "mData": "fecCarga" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: true, sWidth: "15%"},
                                   { "mData": "ptoVenta" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: true, sWidth: "15%"},
                                   { "mData": "unidades" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: false, sWidth: "15%"},
                                   { "mData": "codProducto" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: true, sWidth: "15%"},
                                   { "mData": "desProducto" , sDefaultContent: "", bSortable: false, sWidth: "40%"}

                               ],


                    "bFilter": false, //Quito el global search de la tabla
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "oLanguage" : {
                        "sLengthMenu" : "<spring:message code='datatable.info.filas.pagina' arguments='_MENU_'/>",
                        "sInfo" : "<spring:message code='datatable.info.sInfo' arguments='_START_ ; _END_ ; _TOTAL_' argumentSeparator=";"/>",
                        "sInfoEmpty" : "<spring:message code='datatable.info.sInfoEmpty'/>",
                        "sInfoFiltered" : "(<spring:message code='datatable.info.filtradas' arguments='_MAX_'/>)",
                        "sSearch" : "",
                        "sZeroRecords" : "<spring:message code='datatable.info.norecords'/>"
                    }       
                });          
         }

    }
```

And this is the answer in jsp, only the result of json. No shows the rest of the page.

```
{"validationResultDTO":null,"serieAlbaran":"AB","numAlbaran":"479114","albaranList":{"aaData":[{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"80555","desProducto":"SABORES VAR.J","unidades":18},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"80554","desProducto":"VIT.SAB.VAR E","unidades":90},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81994","desProducto":"VIT.SAB.VAR F","unidades":9},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"71059","desProducto":"VIT.C.FR.VA G","unidades":36},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81997","desProducto":"GRIEGO FR VAR","unidades":24},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81995","desProducto":"ACTV.0%.VAR B","unidades":108},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"12723","desProducto":"ACTV.FI.VAR D","unidades":36},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"71062","desProducto":"ACTV.SJ.VAR C","unidades":54},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"31305","desProducto":"DANAC.BEVARX6","unidades":48},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"92795","desProducto":"VIT.SAB.VAR C","unidades":63},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"71061","desProducto":"MPD VAR DX4","unidades":9},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"8013","desProducto":"CUAJADA VARX2","unidades":72},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"25569","desProducto":"DPS MX.VARX4B","unidades":18},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81684","desProducto":"PS.B.VAR50X6A","unidades":75},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81642","desProducto":"PS.B.VAR50X6C","unidades":45},{"ptoStock":"0170","fecCarga":20141028,"ptoVenta":"350064298","codProducto":"81644","desProducto":"BEDINO VARX4A","unidades":16}],"iTotalRecords":16,"iTotalDisplayRecords":16}}
```

I need to get the albaranList property in order to populate de dataTable and in case of error, get the validationResultDTO.

I don't understand Ajax and the callback function in order to get the results with dataTable jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

Hello, I apologize for not putting the solution, I've completely forgotten.
For IE does not work reloadAjax therefore return to execute the method that loads the data from the list, is not very good solution, but it is an alternative for results with limited data.

```
                        if(isMIE){
                        loadNumTeoricosMensajes();
                    }else{
                        var oSettings = $('#numTeoricoMensajesTable').dataTable().fnSettings();

                        updateUrl = oSettings.sAjaxSource.substring(1, oSettings.sAjaxSource.indexOf('?'));
                        oSettings.sAjaxSouce = updateUrl + new Date().getTime();

                        oTableNumTeoricoMensajesTable.fnClearTable(this);
                        oTableNumTeoricoMensajesTable.fnSettings(oSettings);
                        oTableNumTeoricoMensajesTable.fnReloadAjax();
                    }
```

Comment: You can retrieve json object in ajax response and append response data with dataTable div using jQuery append method http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Tanks for your answer, but I don't know how. I Try with different code without result.